# Tensorflow padded_batch for sparse tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a code, which is like that

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
sequences = np.array([[1,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13],[14,15]])
def generator():
  for el in sequences:
    yield el, np.random.randn(3,5).astype('float32')

def parser(dense_tensor,spectrogram):
  labels = tf.contrib.layers.dense_to_sparse(dense_tensor)
  return spectrogram,labels


dataset = tf.data.Dataset().from_generator(generator, output_types= (tf.int64, tf.float32), output_shapes=([None],[None,None]))

dataset = dataset.map(lambda den, spec:  parser(den,spec)).batch(2)
iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
spectrogram,labels = iter.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(iter.initializer)
  while True:
    try:
      spar,spe = sess.run([labels,spectrogram])
      print(spar, spe.shape)
    except Exception as e:
      #print(e)
      break
```

where I am using the tf.data to get the labels and spectrogram for speech to text. I have put a toy example above, it is ok, if I have a same length signal for speech, but for different length signal in batch, I need to do padded_batch, but dense_to_sparse does not allow the padded batch, any solution where I can use padded_batch with sparse tensor?

Comment: problem is solved....

Comment: i have encountered the same issue.how did u resolve it

Comment: @jessietio, I hope answer can help you, although I haven't added any comments, but I hope you will get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def generator():
  for el in sequences:
    yield el, np.random.randn(np.random.randint(1,4),5).astype('float32')
def parser(dense_tensor,spectrogram):
  #labels = tf.contrib.layers.dense_to_sparse(dense_tensor, eos_token=100)
  labels = dense_tensor
  return spectrogram,labels

dataset = tf.data.Dataset().from_generator(generator, output_types= (tf.int64, tf.float32), output_shapes=([None],[None,None]))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda den, spec:  parser(den,spec)).padded_batch(2, ([None,None],[None]),padding_values=(0. , tf.constant(100,dtype=tf.int64)))
iter = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
spectrogram,labels = iter.get_next()
res = tf.contrib.layers.dense_to_sparse(labels,eos_token=100)
print(res)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(iter.initializer)
  while True:
    try:
      spar,spe,res1 = sess.run([labels,spectrogram,res])
      print(res1, spar,spe)
    except Exception as e:
      #print(e)
      break
```

Comment: While code only answers might provide a solution to the question, they are consider as "not good". Please add some explanation to your code. Describe what you did, what you changed and why you changed it. Highlight the important parts in your code and describe their purpose.